# Pandas: How do I normalize a JSON file with multiple nested lists of JSON?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests, data-science

I'm requesting a data from a API and then trying to normalize this JSON file, it has this structure

```
[{'la_id': '33',
  'store': '1405fdsa6001209',
  'sell': '110aa346',
  'products': [{'codigo': '176690', 'lacre': '15980fd2293', 'valor': '49.90'},
   {'codigo': 'sd4907', 'lacre': '1598a12385', 'valor': '19.90'},
   {'codigo': 'aa4907', 'lacre': '1598a2384', 'valor': '19.90'},
   {'codigo': '1fd307', 'lacre': '1598a20401', 'valor': '169.90'}],
  'payment': {'paymentid': '10a836',
   'value': '259.6000',
   'number': '4',
   'finalid': '4',
   'finalname': 'Cartao de credito',
   'docs': '849763',
   'flag': None}}
   'pagamentos': [{'pagamento_id': '107795',
   'valor': '854.9900',
   'numero_parcelas': '10',
   'finalizador_id': '4',
   'finalizador_nome': 'Cartao de credito',
   'documento': '500003',
   'bandeira': 'MASTERCARD'}]
```

When I apply the JsonNormalize, in order to transform this into a dataframe,  I'm getting this:

| id | store | sell | products | pagamentos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 1405fdsa6001209 | 110aa346 | [{'codigo': '176690', 'lacre': '15980fd2293', 'valor': '49.90'}, {'codigo': 'sd4907', 'lacre': '1598a12385', 'valor': '19.90'}, {'codigo': 'aa4907', 'lacre': '1598a2384', 'valor': '19.90'}, {'codigo': '1fd307', 'lacre': '1598a20401', 'valor': '169.90'}] | [{'pagamento_id': '10aa95','valor': '84.9900','numero_parcelas': '10','finalizador_id': '4','finalizador_nome': 'Cartao de credito','docs': '500003','bandeira': 'MASTERCARD'}] |

As you can see, the last 2 columns are not getting the values properly, they  have dictionary inside a list. How can I fix this?

Comment: 1) Post a VALID JSON structure. 2) Normalize the JSONmanualy and share the result

Comment: @Leonardo please add a "|" symbol in the table's second line to format the table

Comment: Updated my solution for additional `pagamentos`.  Please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    {
        "la_id": "33",
        "store": "1405fdsa6001209",
        "sell": "110aa346",
        "products": [
            {"codigo": "176690", "lacre": "15980fd2293", "valor": "49.90"},
            {"codigo": "sd4907", "lacre": "1598a12385", "valor": "19.90"},
            {"codigo": "aa4907", "lacre": "1598a2384", "valor": "19.90"},
            {"codigo": "1fd307", "lacre": "1598a20401", "valor": "169.90"},
        ],
        "payment": {
            "paymentid": "10a836",
            "value": "259.6000",
            "number": "4",
            "finalid": "4",
            "finalname": "Cartao de credito",
            "docs": "849763",
            "flag": None,
        },
    }
]

df = pd.json_normalize(lst).explode("products")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("products").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  la_id            store      sell payment.paymentid payment.value payment.number payment.finalid  payment.finalname payment.docs payment.flag  codigo        lacre   valor
0    33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346            10a836      259.6000              4               4  Cartao de credito       849763         None  176690  15980fd2293   49.90
0    33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346            10a836      259.6000              4               4  Cartao de credito       849763         None  sd4907   1598a12385   19.90
0    33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346            10a836      259.6000              4               4  Cartao de credito       849763         None  aa4907    1598a2384   19.90
0    33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346            10a836      259.6000              4               4  Cartao de credito       849763         None  1fd307   1598a20401  169.90
```

---

EDIT: With updated input:

```py
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("payments").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df = df.explode("product")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("product").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id            store      sell payment_id    valor number finalid   finalizador_nome    docs        flag  codigo        lacre   valor
0  33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346     10aa95  84.9900     10       4  Cartao de credito  500003  MASTERCARD  176690  15980fd2293   49.90
0  33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346     10aa95  84.9900     10       4  Cartao de credito  500003  MASTERCARD  sd4907   1598a12385   19.90
0  33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346     10aa95  84.9900     10       4  Cartao de credito  500003  MASTERCARD  aa4907    1598a2384   19.90
0  33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346     10aa95  84.9900     10       4  Cartao de credito  500003  MASTERCARD  1fd307   1598a20401  169.90
```

Comment: oh! cool! im my case I have also another collumn with the same problem (a payments collumn that I didn't put in the example) how can I "explode" the value of two colloumns? I tried here to put both in the formula and it didn't work

Comment: @LeonardoAmador Can you please edit your question and update the sample input?

Comment: yes, sure, I've just done this

Comment: Seems like the newly added tag is `pagamentos`   :-)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for each of:

1. Extract the main fields (including key `la_id`)
2. Extract the `products` details + key `la_id`
3. Extract the `pagamentos` details + key `la_id`

Then, use [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge the 3 resultant dataframes using common key `la_id`, as follows:

```
j_lst = [{'la_id': '33',
          'store': '1405fdsa6001209',
          'sell': '110aa346',
          'products': [{'codigo': '176690', 'lacre': '15980fd2293', 'valor': '49.90'},
                       {'codigo': 'sd4907', 'lacre': '1598a12385', 'valor': '19.90'},
                       {'codigo': 'aa4907', 'lacre': '1598a2384', 'valor': '19.90'},
                       {'codigo': '1fd307', 'lacre': '1598a20401', 'valor': '169.90'}],
          'payment': {'paymentid': '10a836',
                      'value': '259.6000',
                      'number': '4',
                      'finalid': '4',
                      'finalname': 'Cartao de credito',
                      'docs': '849763',
                      'flag': None},
          'pagamentos': [{'pagamento_id': '107795',
                          'valor': '854.9900',
                          'numero_parcelas': '10',
                          'finalizador_id': '4',
                          'finalizador_nome': 'Cartao de credito',
                          'documento': '500003',
                          'bandeira': 'MASTERCARD'}]}]


df_main = pd.json_normalize(j_lst)

df_products = pd.json_normalize(j_lst, record_path=['products'], record_prefix='products.', meta=['la_id'])

df_pagamentos = pd.json_normalize(j_lst, record_path=['pagamentos'], record_prefix='pagamentos.', meta=['la_id'])

df_out = (df_main.merge(df_products, on='la_id')
                 .merge(df_pagamentos, on='la_id')
                 .drop(['products', 'pagamentos'], axis=1)
         )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  la_id            store      sell payment.paymentid payment.value payment.number payment.finalid  payment.finalname payment.docs payment.flag products.codigo products.lacre products.valor pagamentos.pagamento_id pagamentos.valor pagamentos.numero_parcelas pagamentos.finalizador_id pagamentos.finalizador_nome pagamentos.documento pagamentos.bandeira
0    33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346            10a836      259.6000              4               4  Cartao de credito       849763         None          176690    15980fd2293          49.90                  107795         854.9900                         10                         4           Cartao de credito               500003          MASTERCARD
1    33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346            10a836      259.6000              4               4  Cartao de credito       849763         None          sd4907     1598a12385          19.90                  107795         854.9900                         10                         4           Cartao de credito               500003          MASTERCARD
2    33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346            10a836      259.6000              4               4  Cartao de credito       849763         None          aa4907      1598a2384          19.90                  107795         854.9900                         10                         4           Cartao de credito               500003          MASTERCARD
3    33  1405fdsa6001209  110aa346            10a836      259.6000              4               4  Cartao de credito       849763         None          1fd307     1598a20401         169.90                  107795         854.9900                         10                         4           Cartao de credito               500003          MASTERCARD
```